# Printing one string over multiple lines without \n

Tags: python, printing, formatting

I was wondering if there was some formatting trick to be able to print one string over multiple lines without the use of triple quote syntax or \n.

The reason why is that it would save some formatting work to be able to print in a somewhat analogous fashion as a column such that using multiple lines for one column entry does not affect the other columns.

I included an example of this in the image[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIZsq.png), where I am trying to figure out a quick way to print 'pix' under the 'radius' word like in the first two columns.

Comment: some heavy lifting needs to be done here and cannot be entirely avoided in the general case. The easiest way to go about it would probably be using a package that does that heavy lifting for you. If it is tables that you are trying to print, I would suggest `pandas`.

Comment: can you provide some output example?

Comment: There is no way to do what you want when writing to a line-oriented device like a terminal. The only solution is to take the data for all of the column values, split each one according to the space available, then compose the output line by line. There are libraries that will do this for you, like PrettyTable: `pip install PTable`.

Comment: If your project can't make use of external libraries as @Ma0 suggested, then a workaround could be by explicit manipulation of the shell's cursor. A related link  is [this](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x361.html). This approach depends on your shell type.